# Error in php: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am having difficulties to get that working properly, there's probably an error with the way i am trying to pass the id variable to the method. I am using Laravel.

My view contains this form to handle the function and pass the id:

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'GET', 'url' => array('uploads/edit', $upload->id))) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Edit', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Controller:

```
public function getEdit($id)
{
  $upload = $this->upload->find($id);

  if (is_null($upload))
  {
  return Redirect::to('uploads/alluploads');
  }

  $layout->layout->content = View::make('uploads.edit', compact('upload'));
}
```

Error:

```
ErrorException
Creating default object from empty value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here;

```
$layout->layout->content = ....
```

You can't do that, as you don't have $layout defined, or $layout->layout. Try:

```
 $layout = View::make('uploads.edit', compact('upload'));
```

or if you are really keen to have it exactly like your code is now, you can do this;

```
$layout = new stdClass();
$layout->layout = new stdClass();

$layout->layout->content = View::make('uploads.edit', compact('upload'));
```